# Logic App standard problem saving Azure blob connector

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I'm facing a strange issue with one of my clients where I'm unable to savle my workflow after adding Azure blob connector "Get blob content using path (V2)". The connection is established and can browse blob and select my file, but when I save , "Save" button becomes activated and lose my changes if I close the workflow, no  error is raised. With my own subscrioption it works fine. someone have an idea? thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: This works fine for me I can able to save the workflow even when I close it. Few of the reasons that you are receiving might be because of subscription exhaust or the disabling of the logic app and also it would be helpful if you share some screenshots of what you receive after hitting `save` button.

Comment: nothing special, only the button "save" is reactivated. When I use Built-in connector, it works fine

Comment: just to confirm that you are doing right, While it is reactivating I hope you are clicking the button again in order to save it

Comment: yes of corse, many times :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @SwethaKandikonda-MT for your time, but I'm also able to save the workflow with my personal subscription as already mentionned. With the help of MS Logic App FAQ , we identified the root cause.

resourcegroupname+workflow name size must be less or equal 42 characters to respect a connection ploicy name of 80 characters.

have a look on this thread:
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/541577/logic-app-standard-problem-saving-azure-blob-conne.html)

Answer (score 1):

In standard Logic App workflow under built-in, I don't find any Get blob content- using path (V2) Action as you said.

[image]

but under Azure, I could able to find it
[image]

I could able to save by doing this even when I try to reopen the workflow I could able to see the saved workflow and the workflow is working fine. Here is my workflow and the result
[image]

[image]

[image]

The only case when the workflow isn't working is when I miss filling in any information related to the workflow.